# Weinberg's virtual soft photon addition to Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, infrared-radiation

I am reading Weinberg's book on QFT, especially Chapter 13.2, talking about the effect of adding virtual soft photons to a Feynman graph in the theory of QED. Weinberg supports that adding $N$ virtual soft photon lines to a Feynman diagram corresponds to supplying the amplitude with a factor of
$$\frac{1}{N!2^N}\bigg[\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\sum_{n,m}
e_ne_m\eta_n\eta_mJ_{nm}\bigg]^N\tag{13.2.2}$$
where $e_n,\ e_m$ are the charges of the $n-$th and $m-$th charged particles, $e_n$ and $e_m$ are equal to $+1$ if the $n-$th or the $m-$th particle is outgoing and $-1$ if they are incoming, and
$$J_{nm}=-i(p_n\cdot p_m)\int_{\lambda\le|\textbf{q}|\le\Lambda}
\frac{d^4q}{(q^2-i\epsilon)(p_n\cdot q-i\eta_n\epsilon)
(-p_m\cdot q-i\eta_m\epsilon)}\tag{13.2.3}$$
with $p_n$ and $p_m$ being the momentum of the $n-$th and the momentum of the $m-$th particle, respectively. The momentum of the virtual photon, $q$, is restricted such that the spatial component of it, $\textbf{q}$ is greater than some IR regulator, but not less than an energy scale beyond which the virtual photon is no longer considered to be soft.

**My question is very specific:** Weinberg claims that we have divided the contribution of the $N$ virtual photons to the "elastic" amplitude (i.e. the one without any soft virtual photons)

> by a factor of $2^NN!$, because the sum over all places to which we may attach the two ends of the soft photon lines includes spurious sums over the $N!$ permutations of the photon lines and over interchanges of the two ends of these lines.

I understand what the spourious sum over the $N!$ permutations of the $N$ additional virtual soft photons is, but I would like to ask **what are the spourious sum over the interchanges of the two ends of the soft photon lines?** I suspect that the spourious sum over the interchange of the two ends of the soft photon line

1. implies including a sum over the Lorentz indices of the additional photon propagator, i.e. something like
   $$\frac{-i\eta_{\mu\nu}}{q^2-i\epsilon}\Big(ie\gamma^{\mu}S_F(p_n-q)\Big)
   \Big(ie\gamma^{\nu}S_F(-p_m-q)\Big)+\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$$
   where $S_F(p)$ is the fermion propagator in momentum space, and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the Lorentz indices of the additional vertices that have been formed upon attaching the additional photon line to the Feynman diagram without the photon.
2. implies including a sum over the transformation $q\rightarrow-q$, i.e.
   $$\frac{-i\eta_{\mu\nu}}{q^2-i\epsilon}\Big(ie\gamma^{\mu}S_F(p_n-q)\Big)
   \Big(ie\gamma^{\nu}S_F(-p_m-q)\Big)+q\leftrightarrow-q$$

So, which of the two is it? Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I guess my question can be reduced to **"If I add a virtual soft photon to a Feynman diagram that connects the external line $n$ to the external line $m$, why do I divide with a symmetry factor of 2?"**

Comment: You are supposed to sum over all pairs of external particles $(i,j)$. We instead sum over all $i$ and all $j$ separately and then divide by $2$.

Comment: Let us restrict ourselves to a solid example: a $2\rightarrow2$ scattering. Let $1,\ 2$ be the initial state particles and $3,\ 4$ be the final state ones. If I were to sum over all pais of external particles I would be summing photon exchange diagrams between $\{(1,1),\ (1,2),\ (1,3),\ (1,4), (2,2),\ (2,3),\ (2,4),\ (3,3),\ (3,4),\ (4,4)\}$. That is correct, right? And you say that instead of that, we sum over the combinations $\{(1,1),\ (1,2),\ (1,3),\ (1,4),\ (2,1),\ (2,2),\ (2,3),\ (2,4),\ (3,1),\ (3,2),\ (3,3),\ (3,4),\ (4,1),\ (4,2),\ (4,3),\ (4,4)\}$ and divide by two. Correct?

Comment: If this is the case, then the $(i=j)$ diagrams also get divided by two with no reason. Isn't that wrong?? And a last question, does that mean that the two processes of "suming over all pairs of external particles $(i,j)$" and "summing over all $i$ and all $j$ separately and then divide by two" is equivalent?

Comment: The $i=j$ diagrams get divided by two because of a symmetry factor in the individual Feynman diagram. Note that you need to deal with the $i=j$ case separately from the $i\neq j$ case as the former corresponds to field renormalization. It turns out to give EXACTLY the same contribution as the general case EXCEPT that it has a different $i\epsilon$ prescription.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I am aware that the $i=j$ case corresponds to field renormalization. In fact, I had a quesiton about it (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768516/weinberg-vs-srednicki-analysis-for-the-electron-self-energy) if you are interested in commenting.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are suggesting that "interchanging the two ends of the soft photon line" on a $n=m$ diagram yields the same diagram and hence we should divide by two. But, in the $n\ne m$ case, we obtain the $(m,n)$ diagram from the $(n,m)$ diagram (if we choose to sum over all $i$ and $j$) and this is why we divide by two? In the opposite case in which we sum over all pairs of $(i,j)$ there is no reason to divide over two because we do not overcount anything?

Comment: And also, assume that a particle has initial momentum $p$ and final momentum $q$, and we study the exchange of a virtual soft photon between the initial particle and the final one: I find that the amplitude covering both $(n,m)$ and $(m,n)$ cases is

Comment: $-\frac{ie^2}{2}\int_{\Lambda} 
            \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}
        \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{l^2-i\epsilon}
        \frac{(2p^{\mu}-l^{\mu}+2iS_p^{\mu\rho}l_{\rho})}
            {(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
        \frac{(2q^{\nu}-l^{\nu}-
                2iS_q^{\nu\sigma}l_{\sigma})}
            {(l^2-2q\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
        \ i\mathcal{M}_0
            +{l\leftrightarrow-l}$

Comment: How do the two contributions above differ by each other only by the $i\epsilon$ description only? They are completely different amplitudes, no? (I have also included the subleading contributions here, I think it should't matter though)

Comment: Yes, to all your comments. For the last comment - yes, they are completely different diagrams, but if you evaluate the Feynman diagram  for the $m \neq n$ and $m=n$ case, you will see that the $m=n$ result obtained by taking the $m \neq n$ result and then setting $m=n$ EXCEPT for the $i\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay thank you so much @Prahar. But I have a last comment just to make sure. Are you suggesting that the $nm$ amplitude is different from the $mn$ diagram or the same, in the case in which $n\ne m$? If they should be the same, why do I get different amplitudes?

Comment: yes, they are the same. It's the same Feynman diagram and it only depends on the pair $(m,n)$, not the ordering. To clarify once more, let $f(m,n)=f(n,m)$ be the value Feynman diagram where photon couples to particles $m$ and $n$. Let $f(m)$ be the field renormalization diagram for the $m$th particle. Based on what I said earlier, we have $f(m) = \frac{1}{2} f(m,m)$ (apart from the $i\epsilon$ prescription). The total sum is therefore $\sum_{m < n} f(m,n) + \sum_m f(m) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m \neq n} f(m,n) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_m f(m,m) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m,n} f(m,n)$.

Comment: Okay @Prahar, thank you so much!!! Everything is clear now. By the way, you once asked me what I was working on. I think this was last year, or the year before. Now, I can elaborate a bit on my project, if you are still interested and I would be happy to discuss. If you like, you can give me your email in the chat and I can try to write you about my project :)

Comment: @Prahar sorry for disturbing you again, but could you please explain why does the field renormalization diagram for the $m$-th particle, $f(m)$, equal to the value Feynman diagram where the photon couples to particles $m$ and $m$ divdied by two, i.e. why does $f(m)=\frac{1}{2}f(m,m)$ hold?

Comment: Have you tried working out the diagram explicitly? What do you get?

Comment: Hi @Prahar and thanks for commenting again. I have tried working out the diagram explicitly, it is also in various QFT books. I prefer Srednicki's, so I will be using those conventions. If one uses the QED Feynman rules, then the electron self-energy diagram is $-ie^2\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(l^2-i\epsilon)}\gamma^{\mu}\frac{[-\gamma^{\rho}(p+l)_{\rho}+m]}{(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}\gamma_{\mu}$

Comment: Now, one can use a Dirac matrix identity and obtain $-ie^2\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(l^2-i\epsilon)}\frac{[-2\gamma^{\rho}(p+l)_{\rho}-4m]}{(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}$, but this does not look very much like the contribution obtained by Weinberg, which is $-\frac{ie^2}{2}\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(l^2-i\epsilon)}\frac{p^2}{(p\cdot l+i\epsilon)(-p\cdot l+i\epsilon)}$. First of all, there are two "remnants" of the fermion propagator in Weinberg's treatment, whereas the electron self-energy only contains one denominator $(p\cdot l)$. The same goes for the enumerator.

Comment: There is no second power of the electron momentum $p$. So, I am a bit confused. Any tips on how to obtain Weinberg's contribution from the electron self-energy? And what was that you were saying about the $i\epsilon$ prescription?

Comment: So having said all the above, I am lead to believe that ot obtain Weinberg's result from the fermion self-energy, one would need to supply one more propagator to the field renormalization amplitude. However, the fermion propagator connecting the field renomralization diagram with the remaining interaction should be on-shell, as the additional photon has been reabsorbed... Actually, I think this calls for a new question, no?

Comment: I have edited this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768516/weinberg-vs-srednicki-analysis-for-the-electron-self-energy, so you can answer this if you like @Prahar. Writting a new one seemed extra :)